# app store - two applications versus in-app purchase

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase

For marketing (as opposed to technical) reasons I'm about to submit a financial services iPad app that comes in two flavors, "regular" for individual users working on their own behalf, and "professional" for financial planners working on behalf of clients.

The "Pro" version functionality includes everything in the regular version and also provides the ability to save and switch between client datasets.  Most of the code is identical, only a tiny sliver of code is added to the Pro version build (although more features may be added in the future that might widen the gap in functionality).

Here's the question:  Is it better to maintain two separate apps in the store (with separate application IDs?), or as a single app with an InApp purchase to upgrade?

I'd rather avoid the infrastructure of InApp purchase, but I want to "color between the lines" of Apple policy and keep it reasonable for users and for future development.

Most "regular" users will never upgrade.  But many (most?) "Pro" users will probably want to start out with the cheaper single user configuration before spending significantly more dollars on the "Pro" version.  Advice on how to package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best bet is to create a second target, setup the project to archive both, and then load them as separate apps to the App store.

I base this mostly on reading between the lines in the various answers about provisioning (at least there seems to be some evidence others have taken this route). I'd still welcome comments or other input from those who have gone down this road (or taken the other one).  Thanks.